# Count how many lines start with which characters

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I have a file with a number of lines in a file filename.

I want to count how many lines start with character 'a', with 'b' and so on in one go.

What command i should execute.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<file.txt sed 's/^\(.\).*/\1/' | sort | uniq -c
```

Or, if you want it case insensitive, this:

```
<file.txt sed 's/^\(.\).*/\1/' | tr a-z A-Z | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 8):

For single character letters:

```
< file cut -c1 | grep '[[:alpha:]]' | LC_ALL=C sort | LC_ALL=C uniq -c | sort -k 2
```

To handle combining characters, if in an utf-8 locale:

```
< file PERLIO=:utf8 perl -Mlocale -MUnicode::Normalize -lne '
  $_=NFKD($_); $n{$&}++ if /^[[:alpha:]]/u && /^\X/u;
  END{for $i (sort keys %n) {print "$n{$i} $i"}}'
```

(replace `$n{$&}` with `$n{lc$&}` for case-independant counting).

On an input like:

```
fix
été
-dash-
éléphant
παράλληλα
молчит
alphabet
3com
foo
ɪ-letter
ʃ-letter
```

In my locale, the first one would output:

```
  1 ɪ
  1 ʃ
  1 a
  1 e
  1 é
  2 f
  1 π
  1 м
```

Because in *éléphant* above (which by the way my version of firefox displays incorrectly as it puts the accent on the `l`), the first `é` is written as the two unicode characters `e` and `\U0301` (combining acute accent), while in `été`, it's the `\U00E9` precomposed `e` with acute accent.

And the second one would output:

```
1 ɪ
1 ʃ
1 a
2 é
2 f
1 π
1 м
```

(there, all the variants of `é` have been converted to `e\U0301` (the normalised decomposed version)).

While `cut -c 1 | grep '[[:alpha:]]' | sort | uniq -c` would output:

```
  2 ɪ
  1 a
  1 e
  1 é
  2 f
  1 π
  1 м
```

because in my locale, the sorting order of `ɪ` and `ʃ` is not defined, so they sort the same and count as the same as far as `sort` and `uniq` are concerned.

(note that you need a POSIX `cut` above. My version of GNU `cut` is not as it treats characters as bytes, so I had to use the `cut` built in `ksh93` for that).

If the data is only US-ASCII, you can simplify it to:

```
(export LC_ALL=C; < file cut -c 1 | grep '[[:alpha:]]' | sort | uniq -c)
```

Or if you want to report `0` for any of the 52 US ASCII letters that are not found:

```
< file LC_ALL=C awk '{n[substr($0,1,1)]++};END{
  for(i=65;i<=122;i++) if (i < 91 || i > 96) {
    c=sprintf("%c",i);print 0+n[c], c}}'
```

Comment: Ok, I quite like that answer, damn you!